# Are there any caveats of creating a FastMoney/Money from a double?

Tags: precision, java-money, jsr354

I [have seen](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2073176/caution--double-to-bigdecimal-in-java.html) there are issues when creating `BigDecimal` from `double`.

Although `FastMoney` doesn't use `BigDecimal` (as opposed to `Money`), I am not sure how either of them will behave when I crate them from a `double` value.

Is creating a `FastMoney`/`Money` instance from a `double` not recommended? Should I always try to create them from `String`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`double` and especially `float` types are dangerous. This numbers are base-2 numeral system then it's not possible to represent `0.24F` directly as the same it's not possible to represent `1/3` in decimal system without recurring decimal period i.e. `1/3=0.3333...` or `0.(3)`.

So the float number `0.24F` when printed back to decimal representation is shown as `0.23` with a change due to rounding:

```
println(0.24F) => 0.23999999463558197021484375
```

while `0.25F` can be shown directly:

```
println(0.25F) => 0.25
```

So answering to your question: it depends. For 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 it's ok to use double.

But the FastMoney class uses not a [floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) but a [fixed-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic)

Comment: Yes, it uses fixed point arithmetic... But there's a constructor from `double`, so I am not sure how it will behave if I construct him from a `double` with `FastMoney.of(doubleCalculationResult, currency)`

Comment: As I remember it will autobox to Double and then cast it as a Number

Comment: And are there any side effects? Or recommendations?

Comment: No any side effects since Double is already implements the Number. The only problem is the value inside of the double in floating point.

Comment: Watch out for a range especially for FastMoney and roundings

Comment: Could you elaborate more on range and roundings?

Answer (score 0):

The floating-point types `float` and `double` are dangerous to use in monetary calculations, but when used to create a JSR-354 `MonetaryAmount`, you will be lucky enough:

First, `MonetaryAmount` (or at least the reference implementation of `FastMoney`, which seems to be what most users prefer) only supports 5 decimal places. If you try to convert a `double` such as 0.123456, you'll get an ArithmeticException.

If you try to convert a double that represents a normal typical amount with 2dp, such as `FastMoney.of(1.23, "USD")`, this is what will happen:

1. Your `double` argument will be boxed into a `Double` and the method `FastMoney.of(Double, String)` will be called.
2. This method will convert your number to a `long` value 123000 (representing 1.23000) by calling `BigDecimal.valueOf(1.23)`.
3. `BigDecimal.valueOf(1.23)` will use the string from `Double.toString(1.23)`.
4. `Double.toString(1.23)` will convert that into "1.23" using the complex rules described in [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double))
5. It so happens that *all* double numbers 0.00001, 0.00002, ..., 0.99999 [get converted to String (and thereby to BigDecimal) as exact decimals](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/TBE) using this method.

So, to summarise, you *can* use `double` to create a `FastMoney` amount, but you should avoid it.